# Why is my build failing using Meteor 1.4.2.3 and XCode 7.3?

Tags: xcode, meteor

I never had a problem building with Meteor and XCode before, but after upgrading to Meteor 1.4.2.3 with React I'm getting a whole lot of build issues.  XCode has asked me if I wanted to upgrade to Swift, but I've been reluctant afraid that it may stop previous builds from other projects from working.

[image]

I converted to swift, but I still am having many errors although less then before.  Is there an easy fix for this?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple have upgraded to xcode 8 now and that has caused all kinds of problems with new versions of swift which are not compatible. This is the case in many areas not just meteor projects.  The meteor webapp has been updated to allow for this so I would  recommend that you go to xcode 8 as well.

Given that meteor generates all of the code you shouldn't need to worry about compatibility

Comment: Thanks.  Upgrading to xcode 8 wasn't the simplest task considering I had to almost empty my macbook air to free up the storage, but it does work!

Comment: Good to know that it was worth the time and effort